# How to generate a new html based on the imported html on webpack?

Tags: webpack

say i have imported a html with multiple link and script tags (and assets)

#### build/index.js

```
import '../public/index.html'
```

and i have this config file

#### webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path')

const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'none',
  entry: {
    index: './build/index.js',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        use: ['html-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/i,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg|webp|mp4)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/,
        exclude: /fonts/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[folder]/[name].[ext]',
              publicPath: (url, resourcePath, context) => {
                let newPath = resourcePath.replace('public/', '')
                return `${path.relative(context, newPath)}`
              },
              outputPath: (url, resourcePath, context) => {
                let newPath = resourcePath.replace('public/', '')
                return `${path.relative(context, newPath)}`
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(svg|eot|woff|woff2|ttf)$/,
        exclude: /images/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              publicPath: (url, resourcePath, context) => {
                let newPath = resourcePath.replace('public/', '')
                return `${path.relative(context, newPath)}`
              },
              outputPath: (url, resourcePath, context) => {
                let newPath = resourcePath.replace('public/', '')
                return `${path.relative(context, newPath)}`
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin({ cleanStaleWebpackAssets: false }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'pooper.js': 'popper.js',
      'stackblur-canvas': 'stackblur-canvas',
      rgbcolor: 'rgbcolor',
      'datatables.net': 'datatables.net',
      moment: 'moment',
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css',
      chunkFilename: '[id].css',
    }),
  ],
}
```

and i get something like:

```
dist/...
   /assets/...
   /index.js
   /index.css
```

But i want a new html with old links and scripts gone and a new link and script tag pointing to my bundles. I tried [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/) but when i pass index.html as a template it tries to resolve links, scripts and assets again, and also i don't think it's a right tool for the job, and there should be a option on my current setup that helps me generate the new html.

Comment: Can you add a description of what kind of transformation you want to perform? I.e. what goes in and what should come out. That would help in pointing out a solution. :)

Comment: @JuhoVepsäläinen html goes in and html comes out. it bundles up the link tags in one bundle and script tags in another and references them in a new html. every css and js file is static and there are no node modules used.

Comment: Ok, I see now. It's possible webpack isn't the ideal tool for the use case as it's somewhat JavaScript-centric. I wonder if https://www.npmjs.com/package/assetgraph would work better for what you have in mind.